# Can resizing grip be removed from an Eclipse RCP splash screen in Linux?

Tags: java, linux, eclipse-rcp, x11, splash-screen

In Linux, Eclipse splash screen and splash screens of RCP applications have a resizing grip in bottom-right corner, which looks a bit ugly and useless (since they are, of course, non-resizable). Can anything be done (in the splash handler or otherwise) to remove it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two options:

1. The resizing grip is added by the window manager. My guess is that the Eclipse launcher didn't specify that the window is non-resizable, so by default the WM makes it resizable
2. The resizing grip is added by the toolkit (GTK in this case), probably because the Eclipse launcher didn't request a non-resizable window.

In both cases, file a bug report on the eclipse launcher - unless you want to recompile it with your own fix.

Comment: I certainly don't :) Reported at https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=354934